# Problema al llenar array de estructuras con doble puntero

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una función en la cual lleno un array de estructuras con el contenido de un archivo de texto utilizando un doble puntero.

El archivo de texto contiene un primer valor que indica el numero de filas que hay y luego tiene tres columnas con 3 tipos de datos. Dentro de la función imprimo toda el array y se me imprime todo correctamente, pero en el main, fuera de la función, no me imprime el array
correctamente.

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
  unsigned char simb;
  int bit;
  unsigned int cod;
}codi;

int leer_tabla(FILE *fT, codi** tabla, int* filas)
{
    fT=fopen("Tabla.txt","r");
    if (fT == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, archivo inexistente");
        return(0);
    }   
    else
    {
        char str[200];
        /*leo la primer fila del archivo apra sacar filas*/
        fgets(str,200,fT);
        *filas=(atoi(str));
        printf("%d\n",*filas);
        unsigned long int codf;
        unsigned char simb;
        char arr[100];
        /*Aloco memoria*/
        tabla=malloc((*filas)*sizeof(codi));
        /*aloco memoria para cada espacio y lleno el array*/
        for(int i=0; i<*filas; i++)
        {
            tabla[i]=malloc(sizeof(codi));
            fscanf(fT,"%s",&(tabla[i]->simb));
            printf("%s ",&(tabla[i]->simb));
            fscanf(fT,"%d",&(tabla[i]->bit));
            printf("%d ",(tabla[i]->bit));
            fscanf(fT,"%s",arr);
            codf=(strtoul(arr, NULL, 16));
            tabla[i]->cod=codf;
            printf("%x\n",(tabla[i]->cod));
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

int main()
{
   codi *tabla;
   int filas;
   FILE* fT;
   leer_tabla(fT, &tabla, &filas);
   printf("%d\n", filas);
   //Así es como imprimo el array:
   for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
   {
       printf("%s ",(tabla[i].simb));
       printf("%d ",(tabla[i].bit)); 
       printf("%x\n",(tabla[i].cod)); 
    }   
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Al invocar la función, le pasas contenido basura al parámetro `ft`. Ya que el `ft` del main no tiene inicializado nada. Otro problema es que en ningún momento usas la variable `fpTdC`. Me pregunto, ¿cómo estás imprimiendo el contenido del array en el main?

Comment: Acabo de editar la publicacion, no me di ceunta que en vez de poner ft puse fpTdC.Es decir que el fopen lo deberia hacer en el main entonces? En realidad trate de imprimir en el main con esto

Comment: Agrega ese código en la pregunta, editala.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<256; i++){printf("%s ",(tabla[i].simb));printf("%d ",(tabla[i].bit));                printf("%x\n",(tabla[i].cod)); }                                                                                           `Pero no me estaria compilando bien. Igualmente en la siguiente funcion que tengo que utilizar, utilizo las variables de esta funcion , con sus respectivos valores , pero al debugear me da que el parametro tablacod es vacio.

Comment: Una recomendación, cuando hagas una pregunta, trata de agregar el código lo más ordenado posible. También acostúmbrate añadir el código donde está el problema (en tu caso, es la forma como recorres el *array*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Problema al llenar array de estructuras con doble puntero

El código tiene varias fallas:

**1.-** El puntero `fT` (del `main`) en ningún momento lo usas y cuando invocas a la función `leer_tabla`, le pasas al parámetro contenido basura.

Así que en este caso deberías de invocar a `fopen` antes de llamar a `leer_tabla` y después le pasas el contenido de `fT` al parámetro de dicha función.

**2.-** Durante la ejecución de `leer_tabla`, en ningún momento asignas la dirección base del array al puntero `tabla` (del `main`).

Es decir, en vez de tener esto:

```c
tabla=malloc((*filas)*sizeof(codi));
```

Deberías de hacerlo así:

```c
*tabla=malloc((*filas)*sizeof(codi));
```

De este modo, podrás tener acceso al *array* de estructuras a través del puntero `tabla` (del `main`).

**3.** En esta línea de código:

```c
fscanf(fT,"%s",&(tabla[i]->simb));
```

Ocurrirá posible falla de segmentación (acceder a memoria que no le pertenece al programa), debido a que, `simb` es una simple variable de tipo `char` y solo puede almacenar un caracter.

La solución es cambiar la declaración de `simb`, es decir, en vez de ser de tipo `char`, ahora será un *array* de `char`.

**4.-** La función `leer_tabla` retorna el mismo valor, ¿cómo sabrás cuando la rutina se ejecute con éxito o no?

Debería de retornar `1` si hubo una falla, de lo contrario, devuelve `0`, de este modo, podremos saber si ocurrió un error.

**5.-** Esta línea de código no tiene mucho sentido:

```c
for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
```

Es decir, el *array* de estructuras no necesariamente tendrá 256 posiciones, eso dependerá de la cantidad de filas que tenga guardada la variable `filas`.

La forma correcta sería iterar de esta manera:

```c
for(int i=0; i < filas; i++)
```

**6.-** No necesitas volver a reservar memoria en cada iteración:

```c
//Este código ocasionará que accedas a memoria que no le pertenezca al programa y esto hace que termine de forma anormal.
tabla[i]=malloc(sizeof(codi));
```

Y esto se debe porque el *array* de estructuras ya lo reservaste anteriormente con este código:

```c
//Esto reserva un arreglo de estructuras de forma contigua.
*tabla = malloc(*filas *sizeof(codi));
```

Con esto basta, simplemente necesitas de un puntero a `codi` que pueda acceder a los elementos del *array*.

**7.-** Esta no es la forma correcta de acceder a X elemento del *array*:

```c
tabla[i]->bit
```

Ya que cuando `i` sea diferente a `0`, ocurrirá un fallo de segmentación (si quieres saber la razón, mira este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354389/por-qu%c3%a9-ocurre-un-fallo-de-segmentaci%c3%b3n-cuando-accedo-al-array-de-estructuras-c/354390#354390)).

La forma correcta sería así:

```c
(*tabla + i)->bit
```

Siguiendo con todos los cambios que mencionamos anteriormente, el código quedaría así:

```c
typedef struct {
  char simb[10];
  int bit;
  unsigned int cod;
}codi;

int leer_tabla(FILE *fT, codi** tabla, int* filas)
{
    unsigned long int codf;
    char arr[100];
    char str[200];
    if (fT == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, archivo inexistente");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(str, 200, fT);
        *filas= atoi(str);
        printf("%d\n",*filas);
        *tabla = malloc(*filas *sizeof(codi));
        if(*tabla == NULL)
        {
            printf("Hubo una falla en asignar memoria!");
            return 1;
        }
        for(int i=0; i < *filas; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fT,"%s", (*tabla + i)->simb);
            fscanf(fT,"%d", &(*tabla + i)->bit);
            fscanf(fT,"%s", arr);
            codf = (strtoul(arr, NULL, 16));
            (*tabla + i)->cod=codf;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    codi *tabla;
    int filas;
    FILE* fT = fopen("Tabla.txt","r");
    if(leer_tabla(fT, &tabla,&filas))
    {

        return 1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tabla[i].simb);
        printf("%d\n", tabla[i].bit); 
        printf("%x\n\n", tabla[i].cod); 
    }
    /* Debemos liberar memoria */
    free(tabla);
    fclose(fT);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me soluciono el problema :)