# ¿Por qué ocurre un fallo de segmentación cuando accedo al array de estructuras con un puntero doble?

Tags: c

**Tengo el siguiente el programa:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}Letter;

int main()
{
    Letter arr[2] = { {1, 101}, {2, 23} };
    Letter* p1 = arr;
    Letter** p2 = &p1;
    printf("%d\n", p2[0]->a);//--> muestra el dato 1
    printf("%d\n", p2[0]->b);//--> muestra el dato 101
    printf("%d\n", p2[1]->a); //--> aquí acaba el programa
    printf("%d\n", p2[1]->b);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema radica cuando se ejecuta esta línea de código:

```c
printf("%d\n", p2[1]->a);
```

El programa deja de funcionar. Activé el depurador y me dice que ocurrió una falla de segmentación, sin embargo, no entiendo el motivo del error.

Un detalle curioso es, que cuando se ejecuta estos dos códigos:

```c
printf("%d\n", p2[0]->a);
printf("%d\n", p2[0]->b);
```

No ocurre una falla de segmentación, por lo tanto, muestra los datos correctamente.

Ahora, la pregunta del millón: ¿Por qué en el primer caso no ocurre una falla de segmentación y en el segundo si?

Comment: ¿Por qué has formulado una pregunta y te la has respondido instantáneo tu mismo?

Comment: @Gonzalo-GC Mira esto: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Gonzalo-GC Eso está permitido y es perfectamente válido. Es una *autorespuesta*.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Aunque, a decir verdad, lo correcto es publicar ambas (respuesta y pregunta) **a la vez** :-)

Comment: @Juanjo Sabes, no me fije en la última opción cuando formulé la pregunta, que decía claro que podía responder y preguntar a la vez xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p2` es un puntero doble y para poder acceder a los datos del *array* necesitamos usar un operador de acceso adicional(*), de lo  contrario, ocurriría un comportamiento indefinido, esto quiere decir, que el compilador queda en la libertad de hacer lo que quiera con el código, ocasionando un posible comportamiento extraño en tiempo de ejecución.

Por ejemplo, el compilador al ver estos códigos:

```c
p2[0]->a
p2[0]->b
p2[1]->a 
p2[1]->b
```

Podría usar de forma implícita esta aritmética de puntero:

```c
/* Son dos operadores de acceso(*) porque queremos acceder al dato de forma indirecta. */
*(*( p2 + sizeof(Letter) * indice) + offset_miembro)
```

Y esto hace que la dirección de memoria del dato no se calcule de forma adecuada.

Donde:

- `sizeof(Letter)`: Devolverá el tamaño de bytes (en este caso devuelve `8` bytes) que ocupe la estructura `Letter`.
- `indice`: La posición de X estructura que queramos acceder.
- `offset_miembro`: Cada miembro de una estructura tiene un [offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) asociado, en la cual servirá para poder llegar a la dirección de memoria de X miembro de la estructura `Letter`.

**Recalco** que el `offset` no lo calculamos nosotros, sino el compilador.

**¿Cómo lo obtenemos?**

Una opción es usar la macro [offsetof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
//Este programa se lo compiló en una máquina de 32 bits (en Windows).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}Letter;

int main()
{
    printf("Offset miembro a: %d\n", offsetof(Letter, a));
    printf("Offset miembro b: %d\n", offsetof(Letter, b));
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado por pantalla:

```c
Offset miembro a: 0
Offset miembro b: 4
```

Ahora sí, empecemos con la deducción.

El compilador cuando vea esta expresión:

```c
p2[0]->a
```

La convertirá a:

```c
//*( *( p2 + sizeof(Letter) * indice) + offset_miembro)
  *( *( p2 +         8      *     0 ) +      0 )
```

Dando como resultado:

```c
**p2
```

El código de arriba hace tres cosas:

**1.-** Accede al contenido de `p2`, que justamente es la dirección de memoria de `p1`.

**2.-** Luego se accede al contenido del puntero `p1`, que justamente es la dirección base de la primera estructura del *array*.

**3.-** Por último, accedemos al contenido de esa dirección.

Entonces con esto podemos entender que la primera expresión nunca dará una falla de segmentación porque esta subexpresión **siempre** da como resultado un `0` (claro si el índice es `0`):

```c
(sizeof(Letter) * indice)
```

La misma lógica aplica con esta segunda expresión:

```c
p2[0]->b
```

El compilador la convierte a:

```c
//*( *( p2 + sizeof(Letter) * indice) + offset_miembro)
  *( *( p2 +         8      *     0 ) +      4 )
```

Dando como resultado:

```c
*( *p2 + 4)
```

`*p2` dará la dirección base de la primera estructura del *array*, después se le suma un `4` para poder llegar a la dirección de memoria del miembro `b` y por último, se accede al dato.

Con toda esta explicación podemos responder a esta pregunta:

> > ¿Por qué en el primer caso no ocurre un fallo de segmentación?

La respuesta dependerá de la forma como traduzca la expresión el compilador, sin embargo, si seguimos con nuestra deducción, es porque esta
subexpresión:

```c
sizeof(Letter) * indice)
```

**Siempre** dará como resultado un `0`. Entonces con esto en ningún momento estaríamos accediendo a una dirección de memoria que no le pertenezca al programa.

Sin embargo, esta tercera expresión:

```c
p2[1]->a
```

El compilador la convierte a:

```c
//*( *( p2 + sizeof(Letter) * indice) + offset_miembro)
  *( *( p2 +         8      *     1 ) +      0 )
```

Dando como resultado:

```c
*( *( p2 + 8 ) )
```

Primero accedemos al contenido de `p2`, que básicamente es la dirección de memoria de `p1`, luego le sumamos un `8` y por último, accedemos al contenido de esa dirección.

**¡Ahí está el problema!**  Esta expresión **posiblemente** dé un fallo de segmentación:

```c
*( p2 + 8 )
```

Sin embargo, hay la posibilidad que esta expresión:

```
p2 + 8
```

Calcule la dirección de memoria de una variable que si forme parte del programa.

Imagina que en memoria tenemos lo siguiente:

```c
0x08 -> dirección de memoria de p1
0x16 -> dirección de memoria de var1 (imagina que internamente tiene guardado un valor entero: 12)
```

Entonces al evaluar esta expresión:

```c
*(*( p2 + 8 ) )
```

Nos da como resultado:

```c
*(*( 0x08 + 8 ) )
*(*( 0x16 ) )
--> *( 0x12))
```

Como la dirección `0x16` si le pertenece al programa, es totalmente válido acceder a su contenido, dando como resultado: `*(0x12)`, pero ahí está el problema, que después estaremos accediendo a la dirección `0x12` (que en realidad era el valor que tenía guardado la dirección `0x16`) y ahí si ocurriría un fallo de segmentación (en nuestro ejemplo si).

¡Esto es una locura! ¡Nunca intentes esto en casa!

Respondiendo a la segunda pregunta:

> > ¿Por qué en el segundo caso si ocurre un fallo de segmentación?

Porque esta subexpresión:

```c
sizeof(Letter) * indice)
```

No está dando como resultado un `0` y este se debe porque su índice es diferente a `0`.

**¿Cómo es la forma correcta de acceder?**

De esta manera:

```c
(*p2 + 1)->a
```

En este caso hemos agregado el operador de acceso(*) que había hecho falta desde el principio. Ya que de esta manera, aseguramos que el compilador use un modo de direccionamiento adecuado (de este depende poder calcular la dirección de memoria de X miembro de la estructura `Letter`).

Usualmente el compilador debería de convertir el código de arriba a esto:

```c
//*( *p2 + sizeof(Letter) * indice + offset_miembro)
  *( *p2 +        8       *   1 +        0)
```

Dando como resultado:

```c
*( *p2 + 8)
```

Ahora sí, `*p2` da como resultado la dirección base de la primera estructura del *array* (básicamente a lo que apunte `p1`), luego le sumamos el `8`. Con esto calculamos la dirección base de la segunda estructura del *array* y por último, accedemos a dicha dirección y de este modo, obtendremos el dato que tenga almacenado el miembro `a`.

**Recomendación:**

No intentes acceder al *array* de estructuras a través de un puntero doble, hace que la sintaxis sea menos legible. En vez de eso, usa un puntero simple.

Imagínate que tienes una función llamada `llenarDatos`, donde su único parámetro es un puntero doble.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int llenarDatos(Letter** let)
{
    int len;
    //Usamos el puntero simple para acceder al array
    Letter* p;
    printf("Ingrese una longitud:\n");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    *let = malloc(len * sizeof(Letter));
    if(*let == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al asignar memoria!");
        return -1;
    }
    p = *let;
    for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        printf("Ingrese valor de A:");
        scanf("%d", &p[i].a);
        printf("Ingrese valor de B:");
        scanf("%d", &p[i].b);
    }
    return len;
}
```

¿Sencillo no? En la función `main` podemos tener un puntero simple en la cual tenga la dirección base del *array* de estructuras, de este modo, podremos usarlo en cualquier parte del `main`.

**Discusión:**

La deducción estuvo en base a la **aritmética de puntero** que se suele usar para acceder al *array* de estructuras a través de un puntero simple:

```c
//Esto:
pointer[index].myMember
//Es equivalente a:
*(pointer + sizeof(type_data_struct) * index + offset_member)
```

Donde esta expresión:

```c
pointer + sizeof(type_data_struct) * index
```

Debería de dar la dirección base de **X estructura** del *array* y al sumarle el `offset_member` nos daría la dirección de memoria de **X miembro de una estructura**.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, podemos deducir que la aritmética de puntero para poder acceder a un *array* de estructuras con un puntero doble sería:

```c
//Esto:
(*pointer + index)->myMember
//Es equivalente a:
*( *pointer + sizeof(type_data_struct) * index + offset_member)
```

Es casi la misma aritmética que habíamos visto anteriormente, la diferencia es que debemos hacer un acceso a memoria de más (porque `pointer` es un puntero doble).

Tomando en cuenta las dos aritméticas anteriores, podemos llegar a esto:

```c
//Donde "pointer" es un puntero doble.
//Esto:
pointer[index]->myMember
//Podría ser equivalente a:
*( *(pointer + sizeof(type_data_struct) * index) + offset_member)
```

**¿Por qué?** Porque con esta aritmética podemos comprobar que cuando ejecutamos este código: `p2[0]->b`, no dará una falla de segmentación porque el modo de direccionamiento **siempre** será igual a:

```c
//Donde "Pointer" es un puntero doble.
*( *pointer + offset_member)
```

En cambio, cuando la posición (*o index*) es diferente a `0`, la aritmética se conserva como tal, por esa razón, se calcula una dirección que no es.

**Conclusión:**

Todo este problema está relacionado en la forma como el compilador traduce las sentencias. De igual manera no necesitamos preocuparnos en hacer esto a mano, ya que todo esto lo hace el compilador de forma implícita; sin embargo, nos sirve para resolver dudas.

**Fuente:**

- [Structs and Alignment](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse351/17sp/lectures/CSE351-L14-structs_17sp-ink-day2.pdf)

  - *Accessing a Structure Member, Page 22*
  - *Accessing Array Elements, Page 32*