# ¿como repetir un struct multiples veces?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy haciendo este programa que guarda informacion sobre un libro. Quiero hacerlo para que se repita las veces que desee, en este caso, 3 veces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Libro{
    int paginas;
    const char* autor;
};

void datosLibro(struct Libro *libro[3]){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        printf("paginas: ");
        scanf("%d", &libro[i]->paginas);
        printf("autor: ");
        scanf("%s", &libro[i]->autor);
    }
}

void mostrarDatos(struct Libro *libro[3]){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        printf("pages: %d\n", libro[i]->paginas);
        printf("autor: %s\n", libro[i]->autor);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Libro libro[3];

    datosLibro(&libro);
    mostrarDatos(&libro);

    return 0;
}
```

En primer lugar, quiero que pregunte las 3 veces sobre los datos de los libros, y finalmente la muentre toda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con ese código? ¿Qué resultado da?

Comment: solamente imprime: paginas:          . y yo escribo un numero y se termina el programa @MrDave1999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El programa fuente tiene varios errores:

**1.-** Los índices del *array* empiezan desde el `0` hasta `N-1` (donde `N` es el tamaño del *array*, en este caso es `3`), entonces, este bucle lo que ocasiona es un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), que consiste en sobrepasarse del tamaño máximo del *array*, en este caso, solo se puede acceder hasta el índice `2`.

```c
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
```

Por lo tanto, la forma correcta de recorrer el *array* sería de esta forma:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Ya que la variable `i` solo puede tomar valores que estén en el rango de `0` a `2`.

**2.** La forma como accedes al array de estructuras no es la forma correcta:

```c
libro[i]->paginas
```

Este encabezado:

```c
void datosLibro(struct Libro *libro[3])
```

El compilador lo convierte a:

```c
void datosLibro(struct Libro** libro)
```

Así es, en realidad el identificador `libro` es un puntero doble.

En este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354389/por-qu%C3%A9-ocurre-un-fallo-de-segmentaci%C3%B3n-cuando-accedo-al-array-de-estructuras-c) explico la manera adecuada de acceder a un *array* de estructuras con un puntero doble.

Por lo tanto, en este caso deberías de acceder al *array* de esta forma:

```c
(*libro + i)->paginas
```

**3.-** La forma como pides el nombre del autor al usuario no está correcto:

```c
scanf("%s", &libro[i]->autor);
```

Cuando leemos una cadena por teclado, le debes pasar a la función `scanf` la dirección base de un *array de caracteres*, en este caso, no lo haces, por lo tanto, ocurrirá un [fallo de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), ya que la función *scanf* intentará escribir en áreas de memoria que al programa no le pertenece. Todo esto se debe porque estás pasando la dirección de memoria de un puntero, que en realidad no apunta a ningún *array*.

Aquí tenemos dos posibles soluciones:

**A)** Reservamos un *array* dinámico de `X` elementos con la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). De este modo, el puntero `autor` apuntará a una región de memoria donde el programa si pueda acceder. Al final solo necesitaríamos pasar el contenido del puntero a la función `scanf`. En esta solución se debe liberar la memoria manualmente con la función [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
//Reservamos memoria con malloc
(*libro + i)->autor = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
scanf("%s", (*libro + i)->autor);
```

**B)** Cambiar la declaración del miembro `autor` a:

```c
struct Libro{
    int paginas;
    char autor[20];
};
```

En este caso reservamos memoria para un *array* de 20 elementos. Esta solución es más fácil porque nos evita usar memoria dinámica y liberar la memoria.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
//Aquí pasamos la dirección base del *array*
scanf("%s", (*libro + i)->autor);
```

Aquí no hace falta el *ampersand*, debido a que, `autor` representa la dirección base del *array*.

**4.-** No estamos pasando correctamente los argumentos a cada parámetro:

```c
datosLibro(&libro);
mostrarDatos(&libro);
```

Ya sabemos que el parámetro `libro` es convertido de manera implicita a un puntero doble, pero en ningún momento pasamos la dirección de memoria de un puntero, eso es lo que realmente debe recibir un **puntero doble**.

**Solución:** Te toca declarar un puntero simple adicional y pasarlo como *argumento*:

```c
int main()
{
    struct Libro libro[3];
    struct Libro* p = &libro[0];
    datosLibro(&p);
    mostrarDatos(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Libro
{
    int paginas;
    char autor[20];
};

void datosLibro(struct Libro* libro[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("paginas: ");
        scanf("%d", &(*libro + i)->paginas);
        printf("autor: ");
        scanf("%s", (*libro + i)->autor);
    }
}

void mostrarDatos(struct Libro* libro[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("pages: %d\n", (*libro + i)->paginas);
        printf("autor: %s\n", (*libro + i)->autor);
    }
}  

int main()
{
    struct Libro libro[3];
    struct Libro* p = &libro[0];
    datosLibro(&p);
    mostrarDatos(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

A pesar que el anterior código resuelve el problema, prefiero no trabajar con punteros dobles, sino, con simples. Por lo tanto, debemos cambiar la declaración de cada parámetro a un *puntero simple*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Libro
{
    int paginas;
    char autor[20];
};

void datosLibro(struct Libro* libro)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("paginas: ");
        scanf("%d", &libro[i].paginas);
        printf("autor: ");
        scanf("%s", libro[i].autor);
    }
}

void mostrarDatos(struct Libro*libro)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("pages: %d\n", libro[i].paginas);
        printf("autor: %s\n", libro[i].autor);
    }
}  

int main()
{
    struct Libro libro[3];
    datosLibro(&libro[0]);
    mostrarDatos(&libro[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Observación:**

Si vas a pedir una cadena con la función *scanf*, no olvides de especificar el tamaño del *array* para que no ocurra un desbordamiento de búfer:

```c
//Es 19, porque se debe dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.
 scanf("%19s", libro[i].autor);
```

De este modo, si el usuario ingresa más de 19 caracteres, la función *scanf* solo leerá hasta `19`.